# List in the form of a string into a real list

Tags: python, list

In Python, what is the most efficient and elegant way to convert string like this:

"(1, 89, 67, 23)"

to a real list? I know, that all elements are integers.

Comment: Technically speaking you have a tuple there, not a list, when interpreted as Python literal syntax.

Comment: I know, but I need lists. I just got a file formatted like this, no connection to Python syntax.

Comment: Then convert to a list; `list(ast.literal_eval(line)))` is the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex:

```
import re
l = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'(\d+)', "(1, 89, 67, 23)")]
print l
```

I use the r just for code-highighting for regex. But here is a good explanation for this: [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do in Python, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l)

Comment: what is the r before the pattern for?

Comment: This won't produce *integers* however; you'll need an additional step to convert.

Comment: Changed it, is there a faster way? Something within regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>> a = "(1, 89, 67, 23)"
>>> a.strip('()').split(',')
['1', '89', '67', '23']
```

using regex:

```
>>>re.findall('\d+',a)
```